React: useMemo value resets to empty when navigating back between steps
I'm facing an issue where my dropdown list (filteredOptions) becomes empty when navigating back to the step where it is used. The relevant code is as follows:
useMemo Definition:
const filteredOptions = useMemo(
  () =>
    data?.items?.filter(option => {
      if (option.category === 'Special' && !user.hasAccess) {
        return false;
      }

      // Filter out options already selected if they are marked as unique
      const optionAlreadySelected = selectedOptions?.some(
        selected => selected.id === option.id
      );
      return !optionAlreadySelected || !option.isUnique;
    }) || [],
  [data?.items, selectedOptions, user.hasAccess]
);

Dropdown Usage:
JSX code:

<Dropdown
  type={user.type}
  hasAccess={user.hasAccess}
  options={filteredOptions}
  value={selectedOptionId}
  onChange={event => {
    updateSelection(event.target.value);
  }}
/>

Steps to Reproduce:

Navigate to the step where the dropdown is displayed.
Select a value (e.g., 'Special').
Move to the next step.
Navigate back to the previous step.

Problem:
When navigating back, the dropdown is empty because filteredOptions recalculates as an empty array.

How are you navigating between form steps? Please [edit] to provide a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, more complete details, and exact reproduction steps.

When you navigate to a new page all components are re-rendered, and all hooks are re-run.
To avoid that, you'll want to use a routing library (eg. React Router, Next.js) so that your app doesn't actually change pages, it just virtually changes pages (ie. routes) when the user changes the URL.
If you are using a routing library, it's most likely re-rendering your component when you change routes (causing the same effect).  If you need to preserve data in-between routes, how you do so will depend on your routing library (you might, for instance, put that data into a context to preserve it).
